# Creating hyperlinks to other sheets with VBA using name reference

Tags: vba, excel

One of my sheets is a list of several (not all) other sheets in my workbook. Depending on several parameters, the list will not contain the same sheets.

I only want help with the creation of the hyperlink. The name of the sheet I want to link to (ws.Name) is being called in. So the hyperlink has to use this, not a hard coded name. So far I've had this:

```
            ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add _
                Anchor:=f_ListeMoms.Range("col_mom")(j), _
                Address:="'" & ws.Name & "'!A1", _
                TextToDisplay:=nomMoM
```

In which the anchor was functioning great, no need to worry about the anchor. It simply said the destination cannot be reached when clicked, and right clicking the hyperlink > modify hyperlink shows the address as this: ['MoM11'!A1 ]. ws.name is the string "MoM11".

I've also had this version which didn't work either because I'm not sure how to put it:

```
f_ListeMoms.Range("col_mom")(j).FormulaR1C1 = "=HYPERLINK(" & ws.Name & ",""CLICK HERE"")"
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong, or can show an alternative method? Thanks!

Comment: the single quotes / may be the culprit, try Address:="""" & ws.Name & "!A1"""

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this format (using SubAddress):

```
    Sheet1.Hyperlinks.Add _
            Anchor:=Sheet1.Range("C3"), _
            Address:="", _
            SubAddress:="'" & Sheet2.Name & "'!A1", _
            TextToDisplay:="Sheet 2"
```

.

**Note**: Usually the SubAddress targets a location in the current file (internal Excel navigation within the document), but the Address targets a web page - it attempts to open the target in a browser

Comment: Do you know why it works with subaddress, but not address?

Comment: I added the explanation to the answer: you asked a good question and more people should be aware of the details!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you need the single quotes in this line

```
Address:="'" & ws.Name & "'!A1", _
```

Try

```
Address:=" & ws.Name & !A1", _
```